# Telerik RadGrid for ASP.Net (web forms) OnCancelCommand Event Not Firing

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

In this [example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/batch-editing/defaultcs.aspx) there is a Telerik RadGrid that provides batch (excel style) editing.

In the link provided above, there's a sample grid with a cancel changes button.

[image: Cancel changes button]

In the link example the aspx code as well as the cs code are viewable, however nowhere do I see any reference to the Cancel Changes event that I would assume fires when clicked.

I didn't include the Telerik example code here since it might be easier to review the code in the link provided, however one difference between their example and my code is that we're binding our grid at runtime at the PageLoad event where their's is bound at design time

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
       DataBindGrid();
   }
}
```

I also added a an onCancelCommand event to the markup:

```html
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGridActionGroup" runat="server" Width="900px" OnCancelCommand="RadGridActionGroup_CancelCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
Skin="Windows7" onitemcommand="RadGridActionGroup_ItemCommand1">
```

But this event never seems to fire when that button is clicked:

```
  protected void RadGridActionGroup_CancelCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    DataBindData();
}
```

I've not used Telerik controls before but I think it might have something to do with runtime databinding.

Thanks.

Comment: Most of the Telerik demos use SqlDataSource for simplicity. In reality I find using the OnNeedDataSource event in all my RadGrids way more effective. This event fires any time the grid needs to refresh it's data e.g. when the user sorts, filters, updates, edits, deletes data in the grid. If you read up about how to use OnNeedDataSource, you should find all other events like the RadGridActionGroup_CancelCommand event will fire correctly when required. More info here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-binding/simple-vs-advanced/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What is happenning in:
    onitemcommand="RadGridActionGroup_ItemCommand1" ???

I've got the feeling that it doesnt let the program continue after that.
"onitemcommand" is happening in every server event on the grid.
check it out.